# How can I automate installation of local "development mode" packages?

Tags: python, dependencies, development-environment, virtualenv, setuptools

If you run `python setup.py develop` on several packages in the same `virtualenv`, you can develop both of them without having to re-install after making changes.

I recently extracted functionality from my project into a separate package, which I am now developing in this manner.

Is there a way to express this dependency in my `setup.py` file, so new developers can simply run `python setup.py develop` once in the primary project's directory?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would plan on doing this. `python setup.py develop` depends on finding the directory that `setup.py` is in. Wouldn't user Alice have package A in one directory, while user Bob have package A in another directory? Or are all the directories set relative to eachother?

Comment: @MarkHildreth - They're all part of the same folder hierarchy in source control, so you can reliably count on `project_B/setup.py` being in `project_A/../project_B/setup.py`. You raise a good point, though, which is that setup.py might just not be the right tool for the job here.

Comment: If you have a list of the packages you want to be set up, all you need is a short makefile-like script that cd's to each project and runs `python setup.py develop [user options]` there. It shouldn't be hard to bang together a master `setup.py` that does just that.

Comment: Develop mode is something you use privately, forcing it on others as dependency sounds unclean to me. Either your packages are independent enough to be potentially worked on in isolation (developer's choice), or they can be merged into one package.

Comment: What you describe can be achieved by using [zc.buildout](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.6.3)) and the [mr.developer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.developer) extension in particular. However, using **buildout** is significantly different from using **virtualenv** to manage your development environments - I don't know if that's even an option for you. If you're not constrained to use virtualenv and would consider to switch to buildout, I can write up an answer to get you started.

Comment: @JürgenStrobel He said _"new developers"_. I agree with what you said, but providing a development environment where certain packages and maybe some of their dependencies (own or 3rd party) are installed in development mode (and possibly checked out from source) makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Lukas Valid point. But in this case you should not use setup.py at all, because it just is not intended for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Jürgen I agree. You can use `setup.py` to still declare your dependencies like you normally would, and use other tools like buildout to manage a development configuration of that package and it's dependencies. But as for using scriptig in `setup.py` to set up that environment: Hell no. `setup.py` should be as declarative as possible in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do believe and fear the answer to your question is simply "No".

setup.py just does not fit your needs. Finding tricks to do it nonetheless will probably cause more problems with new developers.

Sadly I cannot provide perfect alternatives:

- Loouk zc.buildout as Lukas Graf described in a comment.
- Distribute a zipped quick start working directory with everything configured,
  if you know the platform of your devs.
- Provide a shell script which does the whole setup.
- Teach your devs the proper use and philosophy of setuptool (setup.py) and virtualenv,
  and have them call "setup.py develop" explicitly for every package they need it for.

Remember explicit is better than implicit is part of the python zen.
I would go for the last one, but YMMV.

Comment: Jürgen, did you post your answer during the bounty period? If so, I don't mind re-doing it to nab you the 50 rep; you deserve it. ;-)

Comment: I posted approx 3h before the deadline, waiting if something better showed up.

Answer (score -2):

This mod allows use of `python setup.py develop` which allows [development mode](http://packages.python.org/distribute/setuptools.html#development-mode)  installation using local development files. Cribbed from [django-tastypie](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/setup.py).